# How to access off-line research materials

Tags: literature

I am trying to track down an old book chapter -- it's not even that old -- but I cannot find it online or through my University. It’s been cited by a number of people, so it must exist. Does anyone have any tips for accessing off-line research materials?

This may be especially important for people that don't have access too through University subscriptions.

[Also less relevant to the broader question, but I am looking for: Clark, C. W., & Ellison, W. T. (2004). Potential use of low-frequency sounds by baleen whales for probing the environment: evidence from models and empirical measurements. Echolocation in bats and dolphins, 564-582.]

Comment: Did you try interlibrary loan (ILL?) through the university library?

Comment: Ohh that's a good idea. I didn't find it with their online library search, but they may be able to find it through the back channels.

Comment: Yes I've had good success there. Will add it as an answer but wanted to confirm you hadn't tried it yet.

Answer (score 11):

I guess you are chasing the wrong citation (Scholar.Google does not give complete citation)

The Clark & Ellison paper is in the Book Echolocation in Bats and Dolphins edited by Jeanette A. Thomas, Cynthia F.Moss and Marianne Vater, the University of Chicago press. It is fairly new: 2004, so institutional libraries should have it.

To the OP: If, like in this case, you can know the e-mail address of one of the authors, (here e.g. Chris Clark) then send him a pdf request. If not, contact one of the researchers in the field, especially if published with one of the co-authors, as they may help you.

Edit: To address a comment the e-mails, I would add that in pre-internet times, it was custom for students, researchers to sent copy requests to the authors. For this reasons authors had hundreds of paper copies available and it gave satisfaction if people requested a copy. Nowadays, there is always an e-mail address given in the publication to whom request should be made. So, don't be shy.

Comment: It is comforting to have someone confirm this is fine. Something about emailing the authors feels taboo, especially if your email signature brands you as 'not a peer'

Comment: I have always had great experiences emailing authors for a paper that's behind a paywall (some that my university doesn't even cover) - everyone has been very nice and willing to share!

Answer (score 4):

One resource that just came to mind is https://www.researchgate.net/. It allows you to request an offline print from the author without personally emailing the author, which as some noted above might feel uncomfortable.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to a University at a decent sized US University (I'm not sure if this is actually international and maybe someone can edit if so) you can request such documents using Interlibrary Loan (ILL). This is also sometimes called Scan and Deliver (or similar). You provide as much info for the citation as you can and the librarians will track it down through their channels.

I've had very good success with this approach, although it does typically take a few days. In my experience the item is typically delivered as a scanned PDF. The librarians are usually very happy to help!

A google search for you 'Interlibrary Loan' and your respective university should bring up the correct form.

Good luck!